# Python pyasn1 conflict via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyasn1

I have a Python code using sqlalchemy library. It's running fine in my dev environment. The error happened after I moved into prod.

The error message is

> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyasn1 0.4.4
>   (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
>   Requirement.parse('pyasn1==0.3.2'), {'pyasn1-modules'})

Looks like the prod's pyasn1 is newer, but how is it possible not compatible with the old one?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have pyasn1 0.4.4 installed, but your pyasn1-modules package requires pyasn1 0.3.2 (I am guessing it is [this commit](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/commit/43f2ed528ab07315b73a19ccb920c6c9509dd417#diff-b4ef698db8ca845e5845c4618278f29a) that belong to pyasn1-modules 0.0.11).

So you should either bump up your pyasn1-modules or downgrade your pyasn1 to make their versions matching requirements.